# includegraphics with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create an environment with some picture in the left margin. Here is the code

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt,textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=6pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt,bindingoffset=30pt,asymmetric,reversemarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{sides}

\newenvironment{sideletter}[2]%
{\newcommand{\foot}{\includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}}%
\refstepcounter{sides}%
\par\makebox(0,0)[r]{\large\bfseries\sffamily\colorbox{red}{Ejercicio~\thesides}%
\hspace{6pt}%
}\ignorespaces}%
{\begin{marginfigure}
\hfill\tikz{\node at (0,0){\foot};}
\end{marginfigure}\bigskip}

\newenvironment{sideletter*}%
{\refstepcounter{sides}%
\par\makebox(0,0)[r]{\large\bfseries\sffamily\colorbox{red}{Ejercicio~\thesides}%
\hspace{6pt}%
}\ignorespaces}%
{\begin{marginfigure}
\hfill\tikz{\node at (0,0) {text};}
\end{marginfigure}\bigskip}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{sideletter}{imagen}{20pt}
\lipsum[4]
\end{sideletter}

\begin{sideletter}{imagen}{35pt}
\lipsum[6]
\end{sideletter}

\begin{sideletter*}
\lipsum[7]
\end{sideletter*}

\end{document}
```

which needs a graphic file.

This is a result:

[image: result]

<sub>(source: [uclm.es](http://matematicas.uclm.es/earanda/result.jpg))</sub>

This is almost what I want. A paragraph on the right, with some text in the margin as a title, and at the bottom of the paragraph, some picture on the left margin.

My problem is that the base of the picture is not align with the baseline because, I think, `\includegraphics` inside a `\tikz` command considers the origin at the center of the picture. I want the picture to be aligned with the baseline of the paragraph as in the third example with the word 'text'.

Comment: Hi ernesto. Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Try `\tikz[baseline=0pt] \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\foot};`

Comment: There is no difference. I don't understand well the behavior. If I use `texto \tikz[baseline=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=60pt]{imagen}};` without `node` then the image is aligned to the baseline as I would like in my environment, but the graphics is over the paragraph. 

However, if I use `node` as in 
`\tikz[baseline=0pt] \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=60pt]{imagen}};` then the image is included putting the center of the picture at (0,0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found what I wanted. That was a problem with `marginfigure` enviroment. I had to use `marginpar` so my environment is:

```
\newenvironment{sideletter}[2]%
{\newcommand{\foot}{\includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}}%
\refstepcounter{sides}%
\par\makebox(0,0)[r]{\large\bfseries\sffamily\colorbox{red}{Ejercicio       \thesides}%
\hspace{6pt}%
}\ignorespaces}%
{\marginpar{%
\hfill\tikz[baseline=0pt]\node[anchor=base] {\foot};}
\bigskip}
```